# POST Method Always Returns 405 Response

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I have a .NET Core 3.1 API that has two endpoints I am using to test some error handling middleware that I am writing. I am using Swagger UI to test this API.

The issue I'm having is that if any kind of exception is thrown during the execution of my POST request, it will be returned back as a 405 response and not even trigger the error handling middleware I am writing. This happens for ALL POST request across my API, not just the test one I am showing.

I decided to try an equally simple GET method and to my surprise, when an exception was thrown within it, it would trigger my error handling middleware which would then write a 500 response back to the caller. Here is the whole controller code:

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]

public class TestingController : ControllerBase
{
    [HttpPost]
    [Route("TestPost")]
    public IActionResult TestPost([FromBody] string test)
    {
        throw new Exception();            
    }

    [HttpGet]
    [Route("TestGet/{test}")]
    public IActionResult TestGet(string test)
    {
        throw new Exception();
    }

}
```

So why would a POST method be returning a 405 resposne when an exception occurs, but a GET method responds with a 500 response?

EDIT: Here is the example POST request I am making

Request URL: https://localhost:44387/api/Testing/TestPost

Request Body(JSON): "test"

Here are the response headers I receive from the POST:

allow: GET 
 cache-control: no-cache 
 date: Wed, 19 Feb 2020 17:58:22 GMT 
 expires: -1 
 pragma: no-cache 
 server: Microsoft-IIS/10.0 
 status: 405 
 x-powered-by: ASP.NET

Comment: show how you are requesting the `POST`

Comment: @DanielA.White I am using Swagger UI to test the API, but I can add a manual call to the API in my description

Comment: Regarding your scenario, you need to add `[AcceptVerbs("GET", "POST")]` on your `TestPost` method

Comment: please provide a [mcve]

Comment: @RahulSharma the `[HttpPost]` attribute should do it

Comment: @DanielA.White Updated with the request URL and request body I am sending to the API

Comment: I should note that if I put a breakpoint on the line where I throw the exception in my POST it will hit that breakpoint, error out, and then return the 405 error

Comment: what do your server side logs show? is it getting to the right controler/action?

Comment: @DanielA.White yes it is, I just posted above you just a moment ago that the breakpoint in the POST will get hit

Comment: @deruitda Did you try putting the accept verbs attribute on your post method?

Comment: @RahulSharma I did and it did not change the behavior, still receiving a 405 response

Comment: @deruitda Maybe it could be a `CORS` issue. Can you show how you have setup your `CORS` policy?

Comment: @RahulSharma I have not set up any CORS policies for this API

Comment: @deruitda Ok, can you try setting your `CORS` policies in your `Startup.cs` class with `corsBuilder.AllowAnyHeader(); corsBuilder.AllowAnyMethod();corsBuilder.WithOrigins("http://localhost:44387");`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/208144/discussion-between-deruitda-and-rahul-sharma).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So I eventually figured this out with some help from [Rahul Sharma](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1807452/rahul-sharma)
. The issue did not have anything to do with the POST method, but rather the custom error handling controller that the POST request was trying to be routed to. The method in the error controller was defined as the following:

```
    [Route("/Error-descriptive")]
    [HttpGet]
    public IActionResult ErrorDescriptive()
    {
        if (!_env.IsNonProductionEnv())            
            throw new InvalidOperationException("This endpoint cannot be invoked in a production environment.");

        IExceptionHandlerFeature exFeature = HttpContext.Features.Get<IExceptionHandlerFeature>();
        Exception ex = exFeature.Error;

        return Problem(detail: ex.StackTrace, title: ex.Message);
    }
```

The issue was the [HttpGet] attribute used on this method, this was preventing my POST request from being routed to this controller when the exception occurred, which in turn produced a 405 response. Removing the attribute allows the error handler code to run, and produce a 500 response.

I apologize for not adding this code initially, however I was pretty confident that this code was not a cause of the issue because the code in the error controller wasn't being executed at all.

Comment: yes... same to me! if you mark the exception method handler with HTTP GET it will only respond to methods that use the GET version, if you do a post request and an exception is generated, it will go to 405, because it can't find an exception handler method that supports HTTP POST, so by removing the httpget parameter the problem is resolved.